Why should the content of the og:description meta tag be trimmed?
I try to fetch 3 links on Facebook, YouTube and TikTok. Their og:description tags are all truncated from the actual description of the video. I understand that this doesn't affect SEO, but why there is a need to do that?

You may read in the specification of the Open Graph protocol (og):

og:description [is] a one to two sentence description of your object.

Since the definition is a little vague, there is no hard limit on the amount of characters you may use. The general wisdom is to use about 160 characters, although FaceBook for example lets you get away with 300. Different platforms you have cited may implement the protocol in slightly different ways, however, if they didn't truncate the og:description tag at all, it would be done for them automatically and also make users load unnecessary data when visiting their websites. So the answer, in my view, comes down to performance and control over the way truncation of their content is being done.

They can load a lot of scripts and videos. Why can't they load some more characters?

I think it's not about bandwidth but user interface and experience. The tag is to provide a user with a short description of the content, not the actual content.
